# Acacia shrubs in Ohio

Tags: shrubs

Is it possible to grow an Acacia variety in Ohio (zone 6)?  I'd prefer to not grow them in a greenhouse, I'm looking for something that will survive the winter (even if I cover it all winter).

Comment: Acacia is a huge genus and has many members many drought and cold hardy members.

Comment: @GradyPlayer Can you suggest some what will weather the cold Ohio winters?  From what I read, they (generally) need zone 8.  kevinsky suggested two that may work.  If you know of some, please make your reply a question so that I can upvote as needed.

Comment: Yeah not sure on species names, you will probably need species from north America, as Australian and African species are almost all subtropical

Comment: Looks like Acacia wrightii, Acacia gregii may be some of your better bets, I am trying to id one that is growing where I work in zone 6, but it may be a different but similar genus, it has a greatly expanded petiole, and diminished almost vestigial leaflets...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hardiness of a plant is influenced by [many factors](http://www.ext.colostate.edu/mg/gardennotes/143.html) some of which you can influence.

- your local micro climate:

  ```
   - sheltered is good
   - warmer urban areas help
   - ideal soil conditions.  
   - Acacias do not seem to withstand heavy snow loads so plant accordingly.
  ```
- Although the hardiest acacias I could find were good to zone 7 ish the latest USDA zone map shows a creep of warmer winter temperatures northward.  I'm certainly seeing this where I live.

You could try these species:

- [Acacia obliquinervia](http://en.hortipedia.com/wiki/Acacia_obliquinervia) good to at least -12 deg F 2 deg C
- [Acacia pravissima](http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/59172/) cultivated in Europe for many years

[This web site](http://www.growingontheedge.net) is for gardening enthusiasts who like to push the definition of plant hardiness and may be of interest. Or this [botanical garden](https://www.peckerwoodgarden.org/support/seeds) in Texas has acacia seed for sale.

I would try growing plants from seed rather than buying established plants and plant as many as your garden will fit.

Comment: +1 thank you for the information.  Maybe if I grow some close to the house and in an area that's blocked off (inner part of an 'L') I'll have a chance.  I'll try the Pravissima seeds first.  I would think that I could eventually get enough seeds by natural selection to make a go at it.